# How to locate elements of table with dynamic ids using findElements?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have to get the XPATH for dynamic Ids of table. I am trying to get all table ids which have 'sometext' into a list using findElements.

Issue is that they have a similar pattern except for digits in id attribute they vary

```
<tr>
<td>
<a id="text-132" </a>
</td>
<a id="text-125" </a>
</td>
<td>
<a id="test-122"</a>
</td>
```

I wrote following code, it doesn't show any error locating xpath but it prints nothing and list size is 0

```
List<WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'text')]"));
    System.out.println("Size: " + my_list.size());

    for (int i=0; i<my_list.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(my_list.get(i).getText());

    }
```

Comment: The above works fine. I just needed to add an implicit wait for the driver to find all table ids. Adding this line resolved it. **driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**

Answer (score 1):

I  would prefer (probably a matter of habbit) - alternative-   [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

**Selector**:  `[attribute*=value]`

**Example**:  `a[href*="w3schools"]`

**Description:**    Selects every  element whose href attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"

In your projection:

```
List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id*=\"text\"]"));

System.out.println("Size: " + myList.size());
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using both xpath and cssSelector but nothing worked. Eventually, I figured it was timeout issue so I just added that.